# Saving in variables in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, global

hey there i have this jquery combined with ajax:

```
var username = $("#username").val();
if(username){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check.php',
        data: {data: JSON.stringify(username)},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.result == 1) {
                var name = "content";   // SAFE anything in global variable?
            }
        }
    });
} else {
    alertify.error( "You forgot to type your username" );
}    


if(name) {       
    // if global variable is set => do something
} else {         
    // if not => do something else
}
```

i want to check if the data.result = 1, and thats the only way i could imagine to find out if data.result returned is 1.

EDIT:

I dont want to check it via alert, because i will need to work with this global variable later, anybody could help me with my problem? greetings

EDIT :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitto").submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var username = $("#username").val();
    var name;
    if(username){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'check.php',
            data: {data: JSON.stringify(username)},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.result == 1) {
                    name = "content";
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        alertify.error( "You forgot to type your username" );
    }    

    if(name) {
        alert("ok")
    } else {
        alert("not ok")
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: First, with `var` you define a local variable; use global, or, far better, adjust a property of some closure variable. Second, AJAX is _asynchoronous_; don't think that the code following AJAX call will be executed _after_ it's completed - it won't.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable before the ajax() call and assign to it inside your success handler:

```
var result;
var username = $("#username").val();
if(username){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check.php',
        data: {data: JSON.stringify(username)},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            result = data.result;
        }
    });
} else {
    alertify.error( "You forgot to type your username" );
}
```

Comment: i UPDATED my code, take a look, the returned result is:1, but i still get "not ok", why can you explain me?

Comment: @user3094856 As someone commented under the question, "Second, AJAX is asynchoronous; don't think that the code following AJAX call will be executed after it's completed - it won't."

Comment: That is, "result" will be assigned at some later time, after your ok/not ok check.